# SharePoint 2016: Get access token

Tags: authentication, sharepoint, sharepoint-2016

I need to invoke intranet SharePoint 2016 REST API's to retrieve items. My options are CSOM (or JSOM) or REST APIs. I plan to use REST API's which needs an access token. I've looked up documentation but nothing seems straightforward. Does anybody have suggestions on how I can get access token w/o asking user for credentials each time.

In addition, Im trying to get list of new documents that have been uploaded between subsequent checks. Is there a way to do this? Think of differential updates vs full.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get SharePoint 2016 form digest value by doing a POST Request like this:

```
   $.ajax 
    ({   
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/contextinfo",   
        type: "POST",   
        async: false,   
        headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },   
        success: function(data){   
            var FormDigestValue = data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue; 
            console.log(FormDigestValue);            
        },   
        error: function (xhr, status, error)
        {
              console.log("Failed");
        }  
    });
```

[image]

Then use this digest value in ajax request headers when connecting to SharePoint using Rest API:
[image]

Reference:

[Get Form Digest Value in SharePoint using REST API](https://www.codesharepoint.com/rest-api/get-form-digest-value--in-sharepoint-using-rest-api)

[SharePoint – How to Authenticate SharePoint REST APIs with REST Client](http://www.whypad.com/posts/authenticate-sharepoint-rest-call-in-a-rest-client/1169/)

Comment: I had to enter my network creds in the Auth (NTLM) to get FormDigest. But, using the FormDigest gave me a 401 on the GET (Step2). Anything that I am missing?

Comment: 1. Make sure the form digest is valid, for example if a site url is http://sp/sites/dev. then use http://sp/sites/dev/_api/contextinfo to get form digest.
2. Please use the form digest in Request Header in the step 2, it will be used to authenticate with SharePoint.